# Reload tableview after deleting from core data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm deleting all the items in `CoreData` when a button is clicked but the app will crash after deleting and give this error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Code i have try:

```
if let rf = response{
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Cart", inManagedObjectContext: moc)
    fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = false
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let moc = context
    do {
        if let results = try moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject] {
            for result in results {
                moc.deleteObject(result)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            try moc.save()
            
        }
            } catch {
                print("FAILED")
            }
}
```

Comment: also remove the object from tableview data source

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: delete result from your datasource array

Comment: Can you provide a code example sir

Comment: some thing like this tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reinitialize your array or remove all the object from array, also then reload the table after `for loop` like this.

```
for result in results {
    moc.deleteObject(result)        
}
try moc.save()
yourArray = [NSManagedObject]() //The array that you have used with UITableViewDataSource method
//OR
yourArray.removeAll()
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: `Cannot assign the value of type [NSManagedObject] to type[Cart]`

Comment: I dont have enough reputation